# how to convert a one-dimensional array into multimers with a denamic step

Tags: php

how to convert a one-dimensional array into multimers with a denamic step

```
$arr = [
    //GTOUP 1
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Savino',
    'ga:eventLabel: Runestone Capital Fund',
    'ga:totalEvents: 2',
    // GROUP 2
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Misra',
    'ga:eventLabel: Aalii Fund, LP',
    'ga:totalEvents: 1'
];
```

in

```
$out['VIEW_DEAL_ROOM'][0]['Savino']['Runestone Capital Fund'] = 2;
$out['VIEW_DEAL_ROOM'][1]['Misra']['Aalii Fund, LP'] = 1;
```

if step 4

```
if (count($arr) % 4) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 4) {
        $out[$arr[$i]][$arr[$i + 1]][$arr[$i + 2]] = $arr[$i + 3];
    }
}
```

ANd our step is 3

```
 if (count($arr) % 3) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 3) {
            $out[$arr[$i]][$arr[$i + 1]] = $arr[$i + 2];
        }
    }
```

How to dinamicly create array any solution

---

if array changes

```
$arr = [
    //GTOUP 1
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Savino',
    'ga:totalEvents: 2',
    // GROUP 2
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Misra',
    'ga:totalEvents: 1'
];
```

step changes to

HOW to craate array with dynamic steps with out HARD CODE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(__DIR__ . 'vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/ArrayHelper.php');
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$arr = [
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Lauren Savino',
    'ga:eventLabel: Runestone Capital Fund',
    'ga:totalEvents: 2',
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Subhasis Misra',
    'ga:eventLabel: Aalii Fund, LP',
    'ga:totalEvents: 1'
];
$out = [];

$step = 4;

foreach (array_chunk($arr, $step) as $chunk) {
    $val = array_pop($chunk);
    ArrayHelper::setValue($out, $chunk, $val);
}

print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_chunk](http://devdocs.io/php/function.array-chunk) to Split the Array into an Array of 4 Items each.
Than use a foreach to create a new array that fit's your specs.

```
    <?php

$arr = [
    //GTOUP 1
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventAction: Savino',
    'ga:eventLabel: Runestone Capital Fund',
    'ga:totalEvents: 2',
    // GROUP 2
    'ga:eventAction: Misra',
    'ga:eventLabel: Aalii Fund, LP',
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:totalEvents: 1'
];

$groups = array_chunk($arr, 4);
$targetArr = [];
foreach ($groups as $group) {

    $targetArr[substr($group[0],18)][] = [substr($group[1],16)=>[substr($group[2],15)=>(int) substr($group[3],16)]];
}

var_dump($targetArr);

array(1) {
  ["VIEW_DEAL_ROOM"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Savino"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Runestone Capital Fund"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Misra"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Aalii Fund, LP"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok but if array changed to $arr = [
    //GTOUP 1
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventLabel: Runestone Capital Fund',
    'ga:totalEvents: 2',
    // GROUP 2
    'ga:eventCategory: VIEW_DEAL_ROOM',
    'ga:eventLabel: Aalii Fund, LP',
    'ga:totalEvents: 1'
]; you code dont work

Comment: sorry misconceived. But the other answer you put the "steps" into a variable. My code works without a library.